# Serial monitor not appearing

Tags: proteus

My serial monitor in proteus does not appear, is there specific manipulations I have to do ?
[image: Proteus with Arduino]

I am trying to connect Arduino with internet (I runned Pcap before Proteus), here's the code : https://pastebin.com/Hn2bfVFX

Thanks by advance for your help !

Answer (score 5):

Normally the terminal window is shown by default when you simulate the circuit but if you don't see it you can click on **Virtual Terminal** in the **Debug** menu.

[image]

Comment: Helpful, Thanks!